# Парсинг большого JSON

Tags: android

Есть сайт с которого запросом я получаю достаточно большой файл JSON около 20 тысяч записей в них еще подмассивы.. Но есть возможность получать несколько небольших JSON и отдельно их парсить.

Как лучше получать такой JSON т.е. весь файл целиком и его парсить или же получить несколько маньших JSON и по отдельности их парсить?

Т.е. если будет в приложении 5-10 классов AsyncTask не будет ли приложение грузить систему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю у Вас мобильный клиент на андроид, в Вашем случае лучше брать данные порциями, парсить и отдавать результат по частям. Вы не можете гарантировать, что у клиента будет все время хороший инет и если брать все сразу, может быть сильный затуп приложения.

Посмотрите что такое пагинация и как с ней работать моб клиентом.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А вообще например если будет 10 классов AsyncTask это плохо или нет?  Дело в том, что у меня весь JSON не будет выводиться в один список, а в несколько может быть даже 10 списков будет. В связи с чем спрашивал лучше для 10 списков отдельно получать и парсить?

Comment: Если есть возможность создать один класс основной и от него наслдедоваться, это будет лучше. Вы спрашиваете об архитектуре приложения, это серьезное дело, которое требует большого опыта и анализа, я Вам ответил касательно работы с сетью, т.к. это узкое место приложения

Comment: Понял, спасибо.